# TCPDF : Split large image into multiple pages

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to include various images in a PDF. The images are of different sizes. Few of the images are very log as they are complete HTML pages converted into jpgs. When I'm trying to include these images they didn't move over to the other pages instead the remaining part got trimmed off. Here is what I'm doing :

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Footer() {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}

$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
$pdf->setHeaderData('', 0, '', '', array(0, 0, 0), array(255, 255, 255));
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage', 'SinglePage', 'UseNone');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(100);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($__my_image);
if (3 > $width / $height) 
    list($w, $h) = array(0, 300);
else 
    list($w, $h) = array(540, 0);

$pdf->Image($__my_image,10, 10, $w, $h, '', '', 'M');
$pdf->Output($__filename, 'F');
```

I want to pass on the trimmed of image to the next page but its not doing that.

Comment: As opposed to just resizing the image to fit on the page as is?

Comment: @AndyD273 I tried that too but in that case the text inside them becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP [Graphics Draw (GD)](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php) library has some tools that might help you out, like cropping.

An example:

```
$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
// original sizes
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
// resized sizes
$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
// offsets
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
// crop box
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];
// rotation angle
$angle = $_POST['rotation'];

$jpeg_quality = 100;

$output_dir = "temp/";
$output_filename = "croppedImg_".rand();

$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
$type = '.png';

// resize the original image to size of editor
$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);

// rotate the rezized image
$rotated_image = imagerotate($resizedImage, -$angle, 0);

// find new width & height of rotated image
$rotated_width = imagesx($rotated_image);
$rotated_height = imagesy($rotated_image);

// diff between rotated & original sizes
$dx = $rotated_width - $imgW;
$dy = $rotated_height - $imgH;

// crop rotated image to fit into original rezized rectangle
$cropped_rotated_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
imagecolortransparent($cropped_rotated_image, imagecolorallocate($cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, 0));
imagecopyresampled($cropped_rotated_image, $rotated_image, 0, 0, $dx / 2, $dy / 2, $imgW, $imgH, $imgW, $imgH);

// crop image into selected area
$final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
imagecolortransparent($final_image, imagecolorallocate($final_image, 0, 0, 0));
imagecopyresampled($final_image, $cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);

// finally output png image
imagepng($final_image, $output_dir.$output_filename.".png", $png_quality);

// Delete original uploaded image
unlink($imgUrl);
```

Now how this could be adapted is to crop the original image twice.
Say you know that the maximum size for the page is 800 pixels. But the image is 1000 pixels. So you crop it at 0 to 800 pixels and save that as one file, and then 800 to 1000 pixels for the second file, then put both images into your PDF.

I haven't tested this, but something like:

```
if($imgH > 800){
    $diff = $imgH - 800;

    $file1 = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, 800);
    imagecolortransparent($file1, imagecolorallocate($file1, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($file1, $large_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $cropW, 800, $cropW, 800);
    imagepng($file1, $output_dir.$output_filename."-1.png", $png_quality);

    $file2 = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, 800);
    imagecolortransparent($file2 , imagecolorallocate($file2 , 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($file2 , $large_image, 0, 800, 0, 800, $cropW, $diff, $cropW, $diff);
    imagepng($file2, $output_dir.$output_filename."-2.png", $png_quality);
}
```